# Microsoft Teams : Delegate voice calling

Tags: microsoft-teams, voice

Does the current Teams API or Cloud communications API support third party applications, acting as a delegate for a user, to receive and/or initiate a voice call? If not are there any plans in the future to support it?

It would appear all api's only allow third parties to build bot and ivr type applications.

Skype for Business had an SDK for third parties to build apps, as guests, but further development of that SDK was stopped once the migration to teams started. It would be desirable for third parties to support teams in custom applications.

Comment: You can use calling API's in third party apps but those will work only in Teams. You can not use calling API's independently in third party apps.